# How to find locations of images with a particular value in a batch of images

Tags: python, numpy

I have a batch of images with shape `(N, C, H, W)` with N being number of images, C - number of channels, H,W - height and width.

Each image has 2 channels with some pixels of value `[-1 , -1]`.

How to find the locations of those pixels in the batch without using a for loop, since it is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
# creating test data
test = np.zeros((5,2,3,3))
test[3,:,2,1] = [-1.,-1.]

value = -np.ones((1.,2.,1.,1.)) # this is the value you are looking for
np.where(test == value)

# this returns: (array([3, 3], dtype=int64),
#                array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
#                array([2, 2], dtype=int64),
#                array([1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Edit:
To get the corresponding mask just don't use `where`:

```
test == value
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a mask array that has the shape of the batch but with `True` or `False` at the respective locations.

Comment: Yes, I extended my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy.where`. A simple example:

```
x = np.random.randn(4,2,10,10)
x[0,1,2,3] = 1
x[0,1,4,5] = 1
np.where(x==1)
```

> (array([0, 0], dtype=int64),  array([1, 1], dtype=int64),  array([2,
>   4], dtype=int64),  array([3, 5], dtype=int64))